# Paying with the api and saving the returned result in the database

Tags: php, laravel, api, payment

I am not very experienced in Laravel and I am working on a payment method.
I prepared the payment form. The data I send is approved on the other side, but the confirmation notification gives an error when returning to the site.
I need to receive this notification via POST. But the method I applied was not enough.

```
**web**
Route::post('gateway/confirm_payment/{order_id}', 'Website\GatewayController@confirm_payment');

**GatewayController**

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
public function confirm_payment(Request $request, $order_id){
   $post = $_POST;
   $merchant_key    = 'xxxxxx';
   $merchant_salt   = 'xxxxxx';
   $hash = base64_encode( hash_hmac('sha256', 
   $request->merchant_oid.$merchant_salt.$request->status.$request->total_amount, $merchant_key, true) );
   if( $hash != $request->hash)
    die('Notification failed: bad hash');

    if( $request->status == 'success' ) {
        dd($request->all());
        //output null
    }else{
        //Insert
    }
}

**Payment.blade**

<div id="gateway-loader">
    <script src="https://www.gateway.com/js/iframeResizer.min.js"></script><iframe src="https://www.gateway.com/payment/secure/{{ $order->tokens ?? '' }}" id="iframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" style="width: 100%;"></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function(){ 
        iFrameResize({},'#iframe');
    }, 1000);
    </script>
</div>
```

When I say send the form, the payment is sent to the other party and I can successfully pay.
But when returning to the site as a result of the payment, I get the following error.
**"The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."**

According to the returned result, I needed to register to the database, but I did not understand why I could not get the **POST** data returned by the Api.
When I use **GET**, it does not give an error, but an undefined value comes.

I need to get this returning result with POST method, how can I use POST method?

Comment: The issue is that the payment processor is sending a GET request and you've defined the route with a POST method?

Comment: @James The payment processor receives the data with the post and returns the result. When I get the result with get, the data is empty, but when I get the result with post, it is not empty. But when Laravel gets the data via post, this error occurs and I can't get the data.

Comment: The return page provided by this processor. I understand that I have to post the data here. https://prnt.sc/12llvn3

Comment: Im trying to understand the situation here. So the user clicks "buy" (or something similar) and this is a POST request to your server. You then make a POST request to the payment processor. At this point, do they redirect the request to your `gateway/confirm_payment/{order_id}` page or do they accept your request and then make their own request to that endpoint later.

Comment: @James  yes, they accept the sent data and then make a request to this address themselves. gateway / confirm_payment / {order_id}
I save the status and amount of the order they send with this address in the database.

Comment: @James Here the processor post the payment results on this link and I am trying to get the results with this link.
but my POST method fails. I did not know how to call. It works with GET but the data is empty. This is exactly the problem.

Comment: Is your site served over HTTPS by any chance?

Comment: @James Yes.....